# How to use angular.toJson on a angular controller or scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please see my following jsFiddle example where I am trying to push an Angular.js object into a JSon representations using angular.toJson. What I get is just "$SCOPE" as the result.

> http://jsfiddle.net/K2GsS/12/

What I want to do is get the current properties and values. In this example what I would hope to see is

```
{ firstName: 'Frank', lastName: 'Williams' }
```

Is there a better way to get at that data in JSon form (ie not using scope)? Obviously I could hand roll a method that takes the values and pushes out a JSon representation but as the controller changes so too would that function so I would rather just call a toJson type method. Anyone know of the proper way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I can see that you are coming from the jQuery world, but with angular.js things are getting much simpler, please check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/ASspB/1/

With angular.js you can attach events much, much simpler:

```
 <input type="button" ng-click="showJson()" value="Object To JSON" />
```

and then in your controller:

```
 $scope.showJson = function() {
    $scope.json = angular.toJson($scope.user);
}
```

In fact this could be done even easier with angular.js filters, check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/ASspB/2/ which has:

```
{{user | json}}
```

With angular.js you need to "unlearn" a bit some of the jQuery habits, but this is good since things get much, much easier most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use angular built in json filter as

```
{{ user | json }}
```

where user is the Json object to be stringfied  OR
use angular.toJson to convert it to JSON-formatted string. Please refer to my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/deeps_the_coder/vtz6ej8f/2/

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked how to get this without the `$scope`, here is an `angular 1.5.9` example with **components** (they were introduced in angular **1.5.8**).

This would allow you to migrate easier to **angular 2**, too.
And of course you would separate all this sources into separate files.

You should give **`TypeScript`** a try. This would get you `Type Safety` and a lot of sugar syntax and a easier way to programming in an oriented way. Also you could see where a method is defined and what methods and properties it has.

```js
var module = angular.module("settingsApp", []);

module.service("userSettingsService", UserSettingsService);

module.component("userDetails", {
        template: `
         <input ng-model="$ctrl.userDetail.firstName" />
            <input ng-model="$ctrl.userDetail.lastName" />
            <input type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.showJson()" value="to JSON" />
            <hr/>  
            {{$ctrl.json}}`,
       controller: UserDetailsController
    });

UserSettingsService.$inject = ["$q"];
function UserSettingsService($q) {
 var _this = this;
 this.$q = $q;
 this.userDetails = [{
        firstName: "Frank",
        lastName: "Williams"
    }];
 this.getSettings = function (id) {
     return _this.$q.resolve(this.userDetails[id]);
    }
}

UserDetailsController.$inject = ["userSettingsService"];
function UserDetailsController(userSettingsService) {
 var _this = this;
 var userId = 0;
 
    this.userSettingsService = userSettingsService;
    userSettingsService.getSettings(userId).then(function (data) {
     _this.userDetail = data;
    });
}

UserDetailsController.prototype.showJson = function() {
    this.json = angular.toJson(this.userDetail);
}


angular.bootstrap(document, ['settingsApp']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<user-details></user-details>
```