# Convert object to json in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to convert object as json In my `updateDetails` method But am getting `undefined` in `console.log` after converting as `json`.
Whats wrong here?my cod is..
HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="init()">

                <form id="show_details" ng-repeat="data in editProjDetails">
                    <div>
                        <label><input type="text" class="form-control projectName required onlyAlphaNumeric" ng-model="data.ProjectName" ng-disabled="all"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label><input type="text" class="form-control client required onlyAlphabets" ng-model="data.Client" ng-disabled="all"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="projectCoOrdBlock">
                        <label><input type="text" class="form-control projectCoOrd  onlyAlphabets" ng-model="data.ProjectCoordinator" ng-disabled="true"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label><input type="text" class="form-control required onsiteCoOrd onlyAlphabets" ng-model="data.OnsiteCoordinator" ng-disabled="all"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="resourceBlock">
                        <label><input type="text"  class="form-control resource  onlyNumeric" ng-model="data.ResourceAllocated" ng-disabled="true"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="pull-right btnMarginTop">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="projectDetailsEdit" ng-if="!editMode" ng-click="editDetails()">Edit</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="projectDetailsUpdate" ng-if="editMode" ng-click="updateDetails(data)">Update</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
</body>
```

SCRIPT

```
var app = angular
                    .module("myApp", [])
                    .controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
                        $scope.editMode = false;
                        $scope.all = true;
                        $scope.init = function () {
                            $scope.getId();
                        }
                        $scope.getId = function () {
                            var url = document.URL;
                            var id = /id=([^&]+)/.exec(url)[1];
                            var result = id ? id : ' ';
                            $scope.getProjectDetails(result);   
                        }

                        $scope.goEvent = function () {
                            $scope.editMode = !$scope.editMode;
                        } 
                        $scope.updateDetails = function (data) {
                           debugger
                            $scope.editedArrayDetails = [];
                            $scope.editedArrayDetails.push(data);
                            $scope.json = angular.toJson($scope.data);
                            console.log($scope.data)
                            $scope.goEvent();
                        }
                    })
```

This is my json fromat:

[image]

I want to save my data with these names

```
if ($scope.json) {
                                $scope.json = { "project_id": Id, "name": ProjectName, "client": Client, "onsite_coordinator": OnsiteCoordinator };
                            }
```

But am getting `Id`,`ProjectName`,`Client`,`OnsiteCoordinator` is undefined.

Comment: please refer below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819301/how-to-use-angular-tojson-on-a-angular-controller-or-scope

Comment: Yes I did the same thing here `$scope.json = angular.toJson($scope.data);` .why am getting `undefined`?

Comment: give preference to the answers posted on time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing the `data` as a parameter, hence you should not use `$scope` prefix. Instead just use data.

```
  $scope.updateDetails = function (data) {
                        $scope.editedArrayDetails = [];
                        $scope.editedArrayDetails.push(data);
                        $scope.json = angular.toJson(data);
                        console.log($scope.json )
                        $scope.goEvent();
                    }
```

Comment: Can you please try it using ng-show / ng-hide instead of ng-if.

Comment: But that is not my problem..I am struggled at  `$scope.json = { "project_id": Id, "name": ProjectName, "client": Client, "onsite_coordinator": OnsiteCoordinator };` here only

Comment: Sorry, I mean, while you using ng-if, the other ng- components will be executed only if the ng-if condition is true, else it will be skipped at initial compiling.

Answer (score 2):

You need to print **`$scope.json`** not **`$scope.data`**, also it should not be $scope.data when you convert, it should be **`data`**

```
 $scope.json = angular.toJson(data);
 console.log($scope.json)
```

Comment: Sure Sajeetharan

Answer (score 0):

For beautification output, pass second parameter as true for `angular.toJson(obj, true)`. The JSON output will contain newlines and whitespace.