# How to convert an object to JSON in Angular

Tags: json, angular

Found some answers for angularjs like: [How to use angular.toJson on a angular controller or scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819301/how-to-use-angular-tojson-on-a-angular-controller-or-scope) but not Angular 2 and following.

I'm new to Angular, worked through the tutorial, and now trying to build my first live app. I have a credentials object that has fields username and password. I want to externalize this to JSON to send to my web service. I found this: https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe which seems to do what I want, but the example is in HTML and I want to do it in my service, so here's my service:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  authToken = ""
  loginUrl = "localhost:8093/login"

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(credentials): Observable<String> {
    var url = this.loginUrl
                + '?payload='
                + (credentials | json)
    return of(url);
  }
}
```

But I get an error on the line + `(credentials | json)` saying json is not found, maybe I meant JSON?

Did I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use

```
JSON.stringify(credentials)
```

like in plain JavaScript.

The `| json` pipe is only for view binding like

```
{{credentials | json}}
```

but not for TypeScript code.